# History Server running with different Spark versions

Tags: apache-spark

I have a use case where spark application is running in one spark version, the event data is published to s3, and start history server from the same s3 path, but with different spark version. Will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not cause any problem as long as you can read from S3 bucket using that specific format. Spark versions are mostly compatible. As long as you can figure out how to work in specific version, you're good.

**EDIT:**

Spark will write to S3 bucket in the data format that you specify. For example, on PC if you create txt file any computer can open that file. Similarly on S3, once you've created Parquet file any Spark version can open it, jus the API may be different.

Comment: thank you. my concern is that will different spark versions have different event data format?

Comment: What do you mean by event data format? Provide some  example?

Comment: The format of data that spark application publishes to s3

Comment: I don't know whether you get it or not. but Format of data means parquet, csv, json. So, if you write any format, it will open easily. See updated answer above. If it helps, please accept it as answer

Comment: I don't think Guoqiao means the resulting parquet, avro, json etc files from the job, but the log files. He asks about Spark History Server and if it can handle multiple Spark versions.